# Check if a List contains specific types (multiple)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a block of code that checks a `List` for derived types and then adds to first instance to another `List`.

```cs
var bacon = new List<Bacon>(); // A list of all bacon products
var selectedBacon = new List<Bacon>();

var smokey= bacon.FirstOrDefault(x => x is Smokey);
if (smokey != null)
{
    selectedBacon.Add(smokey);
}

var rasher = bacon.FirstOrDefault(x => x is Rasher);
if (rasher != null)
{
    selectedBacon.Add(rasher);
}
```

This method is starting to get quite long as the amount of types increase.

### Question

I would like to be able to refactor this into a Linq statement that can check for multiples types and adds the first item to a new `List`.  Sort of like a whitelist approach.  Any ideas as to how I can do this?

Comment: Mmmmm bacon.....Did you ask Kevin?

Comment: @mattytommo, lol, you will go to one of the thousand hells reserved for punsters.

Comment: @BJSafdie That's fair **pun**ishment :). I'll get my coat...

Comment: Colin Bacon? Pig icon? Bacon list? Can't be a coincidence...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following (if there's typo's, I blame the sidetracking thought of crispy bacon as we near lunch time):

```
var types = new List<Type>
{
    typeof(Smokey),
    typeof(Rasher),
    typeof(Danish)
};
```

**As mentioned in comments,  for every item in your bacon list, you want the first matching corresponding type from types:**

```
List<Type> selectedBaconTypes = bacon
        .Select(b => types.FirstOrDefault(t => b.GetType().Equals(t.GetType())))
        .Where(b => b != null)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Will that compile?  Shouldn't it be `b.GetType() == t`?

Comment: Won't this return *all* the *Smokey*?

Comment: @CharlesMager the `is` is different... a `SmokeyPlus` (that is a subclass of `Smokey`) is still a `Smokey` for the `is` operator

Comment: @xanatos I know that, but it won't compile - `b is Smokey` would compile, `b is typeof(Smokey)` won't.  That's what this is.

Comment: @CharlesMager You can use the `t.IsAssignableFrom(b.GetType())` that is equivalent to `b is t` (but slower)

Comment: @CharlesMager You're right, that doesn't compile I've updated it (checked it on dot net fiddle)

Comment: This will return all instances of the Smokey, Rasher and Danish where the user only wants the first instance. So shouldn't the `Where` be a `FirstOrDefault` instead ?

Comment: @Steffsww It makes more sense to OP's requirements to be `FirstOrDefault`, I've changed it back but if he ever wanted it to handle multiples that would have worked.

Comment: @Steffsww That edit is wrong, you can't use `ToList` after `FirstOrDefault` because `FirstOrDefault` returns a single item.

Comment: @mattytommo Thanks for the answer. Is it possible for the query to return the first item of **each** type in the whitelist?

Comment: @ColinBacon Sure, so to clarify for every item in your `bacon` list, you want the first matching corresponding type from `types`?

Comment: @mattytommo Thanks.  It's not quite there as `selectedBaconTypes` contains null entries for the ones not in the `types` list.

Comment: @ColinBacon I did second guess that, updated my answer and added a `.Where(b => b != null)` clause to filter those out.

Answer (score 1):

Mmmh... Bacon...

```
var types = new List<Type>
{
    typeof(Smokey),
    typeof(Rasher),
    typeof(Danish)
};

var bacon = new List<Bacon>();
// ..

var selectedBacon = new List<Bacon>();

if (types.Count != 0)
{
    // We clone it
    var types2 = types.ToList();

    foreach (var b in bacon)
    {
        var btype = b.GetType();

        // A bacon could be of multiple "types" thanks to subclassing
        while (true)
        {
            // The IsAssignableFrom is equivalent to the is operator
            int ix = types.FindIndex(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(btype));

            if (ix != -1)
            {
                selectedBacon.Add(b);
                types2.RemoveAt(ix);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (types2.Count == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of `IsAssignableFrom` instead of using `GetType()`. In this way, you can have a `class SmokeyPlusCheese : Smokey`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
        var bacon = new List<Bacon>();

        bacon
            .GroupBy(_ => _.GetType())
            .Select(_ => _.FirstOrDefault())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: this won't work if there are multiple levels of subclass... For example a `SmokeyPlusCheese` that is a `Smokey`

Comment: @xanatos: yes, this will work only for the last subclasses in the inheritance tree, but also this doesn't depend on a types list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want the first occurrence of each type? If so I'd imagine you could do something like this:

```
    var types = new List<Type>
        {
            typeof(Smokey),
            typeof(Rasher),
            typeof(Danish)
        };

        foreach(var b in bacon) {
            if (types.Any(t => b.GetType() == t)) {
                selectedBacon.Add(b);
                types.Remove(b.GetType());
            }
            if (types.Count == 0) {
                break;
             }
        }
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Fixed compilation issues. This should work as long as there isn't sub-sub classes of Bacon.

Comment: @xanatos should be fine now